# Anyone knows how to show landscape and potrait using these code below?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add potrait and landscape in my app, any idea why it doesn't show the build2 which I design for landscape?

Hope anyone can solve me problem!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  bool isShow = true;

  void SimpleVoid() {
    setState(() {
      if (isShow) {
        isShow = false;
      } else {
        isShow = true;
      }
    });
  }

  Widget buildColumn(context) {
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height > MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) {
      return build(context);
    } else {
      return build2(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 700.0,
                      width: 600.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        if (isShow)
                          Container(
                            height: 700.0,
                            width: 600.0,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
        onPressed: () {
          SimpleVoid();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build2(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 300.0,
                  width: 200.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 300.0,
                      width: 200.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you call buildColumn widget in the code?

Comment: @JigneshPatel, I didn't build it , I just follow online and copy paste.

Comment: Use this:  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [
      DeviceOrientation.landscape,
    ],
  ), in build2 condition

Comment: try renaming `build` to `build1` and `buildColumn` to `build`, also move the `@override` from the old build method (now named build1) to the new build method (named buildColumn before), Also take a look at [Orientation builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OrientationBuilder-class.html) which might be what you want instead of MediaQuery